# What documentary were Klaus and Luther watching in S3E10?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

At the opening of the season 3 finale, we see Klaus and Luther sitting, eating pizza and watching a documentary on the nature of the universe. My first thought was that it was *Cosmos*, but it didn’t appear to be Carl Sagan and what I remember of what was said doesn’t seem to be in the transcript.

From what I recall, the narrator was musing on the nature of knowledge and reality, talking about how people believed in a clockwork universe and before that in turtles flying through space, and how can we ever truly know anything?

Comment: I thought it was a movie within a movie, but I could be wrong. Nothing referenced in the credit as far as I can tell.

Comment: @zmike Definitely possible! Would certainly be a great answer if anyone can confirm it.